# Display Power Bi dashboard in JSF page

Tags: jsf, powerbi

I want to know how to render a `power bi dashboard` in a `jsf application`, but not show the link in the code for others to access.

I´ve looked at `Google`, but didn´t found anything goood.

Only for `Angular`

Comment: And the 'angular' solution cannot be extrapolated to JSF (e.g. it is via an iframe or...)... For us  non-powerbi users it is next to impossible to answer but with more information from your side we might be able to help

Answer (score 1):

You must embed the report/dashboard in your web application using the [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). Make the authentication and other API calls server-side. See the official docs [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) for more information. There is also an [Angular client](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Angular) from Microsoft.

First you need to know that there are two modes for embedding Power BI - `user owns data` and `app owns data`. With the first mode, when embedding, the user will authenticate itself using it's own Power BI Pro account, i.e. each of your users needs Power BI Pro license. With the later one, you need only one "master account", which will be used for authentication. In your case you will probably go for `app owns data`.

Basically you need to do the following:

- Register an application - go to [dev.powerbi.com/apps](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) and register an application. Select which permissions to grant it (if you aren't sure, for your first tests simply grant them all). Copy the guid - this is the app ID, a.k.a. client ID.
- Next step is to authenticate from your application and get an access token. Use [Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) for that - call some of the `acquireToken` methods of `AuthenticationContext` class.
- Use this access token to call the Power BI REST API and get the `embedUrl` of the element you want to embed, e.g. [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#report).
- Use [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) to actually embed this element. You need to initialize one [embed configuration class](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) and pass information about element type (report, dashboard, tile), where to find it (embedUrl), authentication (access token), some other configuration options (show or hide filters pane, navigation, etc.), filters to be applied and so on. In case you will use the access token acquired above, set `tokenType` to be `AAD`. This token has many privileges, so for security reasons you may want to use `Embed` token instead. In this case use the access token to call the REST API again (e.g. [Reports GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup)). This way the primary access token will never be visible to the client. But note that this will require a dedicated capacity to be assigned to the workspace, where the report is published (i.e. you will need to buy [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Power BI Embedded](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-embedded/)).
- Call `powerbi.embed` method of the JavaScript client pass the embedded configuration to visualize this Power BI element in your app.